# match a row value to a column value, and rename the row

Tags: sorting, awk, match

I have a file with the following header:

File 1:

```
location, nameA, nameB, nameC
```

and a second file with the format:

File2:

```
ID_number, names            
101, nameA            
102, nameB                      
103, nameC
```

I would like to match the row names from File1 to those in column 2 of File2, and if they match replace the names in the header with the ID number. So that in the end, the resulting file would like:

File 1:

```
location, 101, 102, 103
```

I've mostly being trying with `awk` to do this but I can't get it to produce anything and I'm not sure how to ask it to do the last part of what I want.

```
awk -F "," '{print $2}'  file2.csv | while read i; do awk 'NR=1;{for (j=0;j<=NF;j++) {if ($j == $i) printF $j; }}' file1.csv;done > test.csv
```

It's a really large file with thousands of columns and rows, so I just put up a simplified version of the files in my question here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work if your csv fields have no embedded commas. It also assumes that both files have a header line.

```
awk '

  BEGIN { FS=","; OFS=", " }

  FNR == 1 {       # if it is the header line
    if (NR != 1)     # if it is the second file
      print            # print it
    next             # go to next line of file
  }

  { gsub(/ +/, "") }  # compress spaces

  NR == FNR {         # if it is the first file
    a[$2] = $1        # save the info
    next              # go to next line of file
  }

  {
    $2=a[$2]; $3=a[$3]; $4=a[$4]  # swap names
    print                         # print line
  }

' file2.csv file1.csv
```

---

Test files:

file1.csv

```
location, nameA, nameB, nameC
Earth, Chuck, Edward, Bob
The Moon, Bob, Doris, Al
```

file2.csv

```
ID_number, names
101, Al
102, Bob
103, Chuck
104, Doris
105, Edward
```

Output:

```
location, nameA, nameB, nameC
Earth, 103, 105, 102
TheMoon, 102, 104, 101
```

Comment: could you tell me what the a[$2] function is doing? also I wanted to change the header so rather than it being 'Chuck', 'Edward' and 'Bob' changing to 103,105,102- nameA,nameB and nameC would change to 103, 105,102.